# Ionic 4: broken menu and content styles on ios

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a problem which is better described in GIF:

[image: the bug]

The parent page is "Challenges" and it contains a link to "Challenge creation". The bug happens when you go to that link and then open "Challenges" again (see the GIF).

The real app is more complex and after a lot of time of debugging I tried to remove components/services/utils one by one and I ended up with a simplest app of two pages. The bug is still there. It happens only in "ios" mode. I think it's somehow affected by ionic animations. Maybe the menu is moved too far to the left when it hides and it pulls the content to the left as well.

I tried:

- different browsers (btw it happens on a real device too)
- different computers
- to create a new ionic project with similar functionality of
  two pages (which works fine) and compare it to my project

Nothing helped. Has anybody faced this bug?

**Source code:** https://github.com/i-chornyi/ios-menu-bug

Comment: This issue might be due to the position of  <ion-router-outlet/>

Comment: @AnkushJain I compared it to a new ionic project and it's generated in the same way. Don't see any issue. Can you please tell more where do you see the problem?

Answer (score 0):

So I copied the code from my project to a newly generated one and the bug doesn't appear. What caused it is still a mystery for me.